# change parent li ID onclick of a link

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, anchor

```
<div id="content-container">
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a  href="http://mysite/ClassifiedPrograms/Pages/Training1.aspx">Training1</a></li>
<li id="link2" ><a  href="http://mysite/ClassifiedPrograms/Pages/Training2.aspx">Training2</a></li>

<li id="link3"  ><a href="http://mysite/ClassifiedPrograms/Pages/Training3.aspx">Training3</a></li>
<li id="link4" ><a href="http://mysite/ClassifiedPrograms/Pages/Training4.aspx">Training4</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

When any link is clicked, onclick of that link should change the parent li id and make it clickedlink1 if link1 was clicked. How do i do that in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class of the `li` when the link is clicked will not necessarily help here as that will reset as soon as the new page loads.

You could instead use this:

```
$("a:visited").parent("li").addClass("is_visited");
```

Which will add the class "is_visited" to any `li` where the link has been visited.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be changing ID's, as they're just that (in my opinion).

In this case I'd track what's been clicked with classes, using the jQuery `addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()`, so once clicked you add the class `clicked` to the parent `li` element.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event){
         $(this).parent().toggleClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

as a rough example to track the clicked state, then you can do a `$(".clicked")` selector to get those elements.

Answer (score 2):

with jQuery:

```
$('#content-container a).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().attr('id', 'clicked' + (this).attr('id'));
});
```

but you should'nt really change the id, you could rather set a class

```
$('#content-container a).click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent().addClass('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add that number to the link somehow, maybe a `data-nr` attribute.

Then:

1. Assign an event listener to the links

   `$('a').click(function(){  });`
2. Extract the number

   `var nr = $(this).attr('data-nr');`
3. Set the parent id

   `$(this).parent().attr('id', 'clickedlink'+nr);`

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the head of your site or in any Javascript-File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$('a').click(function () {
$(this).parent().attr('id', 'clicked' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content-container a").click(function(){
          var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
          $(this).parent().attr("id","clicked" + id);

    });        
});​
```